# Efficient concatenation of huge files in C/C++

Tags: c++

I have a tool that produces a list of ten huge files whose combined sizes sum up ~1.2TB. Each file is a serialized vector of `size_t` values, and the tool has to concatenate all the files in one super huge file `ct_file`. However, it has to invert the values of each file `fx` before appending the data to `ct_file`. This is a simple task that I implemented in semi-external mode, but it is painfully slow because (I assume) the OS cache infrastructure gets overwhelmed due to the massiveness of the inputs.

This is how my source code in C++ looks like (sort of):

```
size_t BUFFER_SIZE = 1024*1024*8/sizeof(size_t) //8MB for the buffer
size_t buffer[BUFF_SIZE]={0};

std::ofstream res(ct_file, std::ios::out | std::binary);

for(size_t i=0; i<10;i++){
    std::string file = list_of_files[i]; 
    std::ifstream tmp_i_file(file, std::ifstream::binary);

    tmp_i_file.seekg(0, std::ifstream::end);
    len = tmp_i_file.tellg()/sizeof(size_t); // number of size_t values in the current file
    tmp_i_file.seekg (0, std::ifstream::beg);

    if(len>0){
        rem=len;
        to_read = std::min<size_t>(BUFF_SIZE, len);

        while(true){//read the data in the file from right to left
            tmp_i_file.seekg( (rem - to_read) * sizeof(size_t));
            tmp_i_file.read((char *)buffer, sizeof(size_t)*to_read);
            assert(tmp_i_file.good());

            //invert data
            start =0;end=to_read-1;
            while(start<end){
                std::swap(buffer[start++], buffer[end--]);
            }

            of.write((char *)buffer, sizeof(size_t)*to_read);
            assert(of.good());

            rem -= tmp_i_file.gcount()/sizeof(size_t);
            to_read = std::min<size_t>(BUFF_SIZE, rem);
            if(to_read == 0) break;
        }
        tmp_i_file.close();
    }
}
```

The code above does what I need. However, as explained, it is extremely slow in massive inputs. I am using a machine with 700 GB of RAM, and this code fills the page cache (and the swap memory) entirely.

I am aware I can use things like mapped files or `O_DIRECT` to speed things up, but I've seen many arguments on the internet in favour and against them. The main conclusion is that `mmap` will not improve things if the access pattern is sequential and, on the other hand, `O_DIRECT` does not always guarantee a speed up. I am hesitant to use those alternatives because the access pattern of my code is almost sequential as the input files are read backward and the output file is filled sequentially from left to right.

Nowadays, in 2023, what would you recommend to implement this task efficiently when the input is in the order of terabytes? The code is supposed to run on Linux-based servers.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What does it mean to invert values of type `size_t`, which is unsigned?

Comment: Each file is a list of size_t values. For instance, a file containing the values 4,5,6,1 will be stored as 1, 6, 5, 4 in the output file.

Comment: @AAA: In that case, it would probably be better to write `"it has to reverse the order of the values of each file"` instead of `"it has to invert the values of each file"`.

Comment: Ok.  And from your code, you want to perform such reordering on each 8MB chunk, yes? Not on the overall file contents?

Comment: I suspect that you're just running into the write performance of your target disk; the page cache is filling up because *your code is more than fast enough*, so it produces output data faster than the disk can write it. Maybe you want to look into kernel tunables to control that behavior by forcing your program to block sooner.

Comment: @JohnBollinger yes, exactly

Comment: How slow is "extremely slow" compared to your disk write speed?

Comment: To evaluate whether hardware performance is the bottleneck, you could compare with how long it takes to just `cat` the files together without reordering (to a physical result file).  I don't think you can expect your program to run faster than that.

Comment: @EDD I tested my disk speed using `dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/laptop.bin bs=1G count=1 oflag=direct` and I obtained 182 MB/s. Not sure if the result is totally accurate as the server is also running my tool, which has been stuck in the code I posted in my question for at least 3 hours (probably more).

Comment: 1.2 TB@ 182 MB/s is 6600s so around two hours. More if you are reading at the same time. Whether it's far behind expectation also depends on how far it has progressed.

Comment: You should probably investigate where most of the time is going. CPU load? Is there significant Writeback in /proc/meminfo?

Comment: @teapot418 according to htop, the CPU% of the process is always 12%-30%, and most of the time the process is in state D. So I guess it is spending most of the time doing I/O operations.

Comment: Don't know what your tool is, but I once used a conversion tool that produced a bunch of files, and then combined them. The solution was (of course?) to change the code to produce all the results in a single file from the start. It *did* in fact work 10 times faster that way!

Comment: @AAA making the streams async may give a minor performance boost, if your code is partially I/O bound. [async_ofilebuf](https://github.com/Ambeco/SortManyInts/blob/master/SortManyInts/SortManyInts/async_ofilebuf.h) and [async_ifilebuf](https://github.com/Ambeco/SortManyInts/blob/master/SortManyInts/SortManyInts/async_ifilebuf.h) This would result in the disk working at 100%, rather than waiting for the CPU to issue the next read or write, with almost no change to your code.

Comment: iostreams is the slowest thing in the entire Earth. This has been proven over and over. Never use it unless for giggles and fun. Rely on the standard C library for speed instead.

Comment: Unless you have a gigantic hard drive, you are probably running into disk fragmentation.  As your program proceeds, it creates more and more fragments.  You may want to defragment your hard drive before starting your program, and if you can, in the middle of the operation.